# modx - disable cache for single snippet

Tags: caching, code-snippets, modx

How to disable cache for a snippet?

here is my code

chunk -

[[!get_homepage? &file=`/customSnippets/homepage.php`]]

get_homepage snippet

getOption('base_path').$file;

it returns same content when I use different browse. (I did some browser check in /customSnippets/homepage.php file)
any idea?

thanks

Comment: Weird. Adding the `!` should make it an uncached snippet.

Can you make your 'chunk' an uncached snippet and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

```
[[!get_homepage? &file='[[!homePageSnippet]]']]
```

Dont call a file, use snippet uncached !